# Flutter Firebase Database "The method 'forEach' was called on null."

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a File called Database.dart where i inserted "Dummy" Data and set up the Connection to Firebase. With the Meals.dart i want to show the Data later on the Screen. Now i want to show this Dummy Data in my Debug Console. I tried to change the "mealList" in the Meals.dart but i didn't figured it out what the Problem in my Code is.

**This is the Error Code i get.**

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Meals(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<List<MealsAndWhen>>], state: _MealsState#ed4e6):
The method 'forEach' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (MealsAndWhen) => Null)

The relevant error-causing widget was
    Meals 
lib/…/MealPlan/mealplan.dart:23
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      _MealsState.build 
package:mealapp/…/Widgets/meals.dart:17
#2      StatefulElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4619
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4502
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4675
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter:
flutter:
```

**My Database.dart code is**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:mealapp/models/Widgets/whenAndWhatToEat.dart';

class DatabaseService {

  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({ this.uid });

  // collection reference
  final CollectionReference mealCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('mealList');


  Future updateUserData(String shopping, String name, String whatEat, String whenEat) async {

    return await mealCollection.document(uid).setData({
      'shopping': shopping,
      'name': name,
      'whatEat': whatEat,
      'whenEat': whenEat,
    });    
  }

  //Meal List from Snapshot
  List<MealsAndWhen> _mealAndWhenListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc){
      return MealsAndWhen(
        whenEat: doc.data['When'] ?? '',
        whatEat: doc.data['What'] ?? '',
      );
    }).toList();
  }


  //get shoppingList Stream
  Stream<List<MealsAndWhen>> get mealList {
    return mealCollection.snapshots()
    .map(_mealAndWhenListFromSnapshot);
  }

}
```

**My Meals.dart code is**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mealapp/models/Widgets/whenAndWhatToEat.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class Meals extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MealsState createState() => _MealsState();
}

class _MealsState extends State<Meals> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    final meals = Provider.of<List<MealsAndWhen>>(context);
    meals.forEach((meals){
      print(meals.whatEat);
      print(meals.whenEat);
    });


    return Container(

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your forEach in a check for null.
Because it takes some time for a reply from firebase.

> The method 'forEach' was called on null.

```
if (meals != null) {
    meals.forEach((meals){
      print(meals.whatEat);
      print(meals.whenEat);
    });
}
```

In your return area do something like:

```
return (meals == null || meals.isEmpty) ? Text('empty') : ListView.builder(
        itemCount: meals.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          print(meals[index].whatEat);
          print(meals[index].whenEat);
          return text('Something');
        },
      );
```

Comment: Thank you! Your Answere helped me out! Greetings

Comment: @Tempelritter if the answer of Jotcode was helpful you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

you wrongly call the properties.
you define the properties `'whatEat': whatEat` and `'whenEat': whenEat`.

Then, you call the properties using different name, `['When']` and `['What']`.

Solution:
Try to change `['When']` into `['whenEat']` and `['What']` into `['whatEat']`